# SQL in Power Query using ODBC

Tags: teradata, powerquery

I have a Table with following Columns:

```
Account_No, Start_Date, End_Date
```

I downloaded this table into power query using **SQL** Select command through **ODBC**.

Now i want to get sum and count of transactions of all accounts given in the above table from `Start_Date` to `End_Date` from another Table. e.g. `Transaction_Table`. What should i do to get my desired results.

Regards

KAM

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need Power Query at all at this point.
Assuming your DB server is MS SQL Server 2008 or higher,

```
WITH t1([Account_No], StartDate, EndDate) As
(
    SELECT [Account_No], StartDate = MIN([Start_Date]), EndDate = MAX([End_Date])
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY Account_No
)
SELECT 
      [Account_No]
    , Amount = SUM([Field_Transaction_Total])
    , [Transaction_Count] = COUNT([Field_Transaction_ID]) 
FROM [Transaction_Table] t2
INNER JOIN t1 ON t2.[Account_No] = t1.Account_No
    AND t2.[Field_Transaction_Date] BETWEEN t1.StartDate AND t1.EndDate
```

You can also use **a copy** of a query inside WITH block to get this table with accounts and dates to Excel, if you need it.

If you use another SQL Server, just refactor this code, I hope you've got the idea.

Comment: Dear Mr. Eugene, Thanks for your response, however i am getting following error. "Details: "ODBC: ERROR [42000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Syntax error, expected something like a name or a Unicode delimited identifier between the word 'Amount' and '='. " While running the code. Can you please tell me what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: my code is as following <code> With t1(Account_Num, Account_Status_End_Dt) as
(
Select Account_Num, Acct_Status_Type_Cd, Acct_Status_Reason_Cd, Acct_Status_End_Dt from dp_view_t24_ibg.Account_Status_hist where Account_Num in (Select Account_Num from dp_tab.agreement where branch_party_id = '5520')
)
Select
 Account_Num
 , Amount = Sum(Event_Amt)
 , Transaction_Count = Count(Event_Amt)
From Dp_view_T24_ibg.event t2
Inner Join t1 ON t2.Account_Num = t1.Account_Num
 AND t2.Event_Start_Dt Between t1.Account_Status_End_Dt AND '2016-06-30'</code>

Comment: As I can see you use Teradata. While I have no experience with this RDBMS, I can offer you general troubleshooting path.

Comment: @KhawarArmeerMalik :
Please format your code next time, it's hard to read it as is.

Check if a query inside `WITH` block runs OK - run it separately.
If it doesn't, replace `ColumnName = expression` with `expression as ColumnName`.

Comment: Apologies for writing in such a way. Further to your guidance i am getting following error now. `DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [42000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Syntax error: Data Type "Account_Num" does not match a Defined Type name. 
Details:
    DataSourceKind=Odbc
    DataSourcePath=dsn=IBG_PDM
    OdbcErrors=Table` My code is in next post.

Comment: ```with t1(Account_Num, Acct_Status_End_Dt) As  (  Select Account_Num, Acct_Status_End_Dt from dp_view_t24_ibg.account_status_hist where account_num in ('1001','1002','1003')  Group by Account_Num, Acct_Status_End_Dt  )  Select t2(Account_Num,  Sum(Event_Amt) = Tot_Amt,  Count(Event_Start_Dt) = Tot_Count  from dp_view_t24_ibg.event)  inner join t1 ON t1.Account_Num = t2.Account_Num  AND t2.Event_Start_Dt BETWEEN Acct_Status_End_Dt and Corrent_Date()```

Comment: Forgive me for i am not able to write in a formatted way. Please help.

Comment: I see you can! ;) Just use Enter to split lines.
Ok. Of course it will fail, since you don't have field Account_Num in your table, it is example and supposed to be replaced with your Account Number field.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `GROUP BY` statement in the **SQL** you wrote, or you could filter the table based on the `Start_Date` to the `End_Date` and then right-click on the column you want to count and choose `Group By`.

Comment: Dear Alejandro, I use this command to get first table. <code> Select Account_No, Start_Date, End_Date from Customer_Table where Branch_ID = '4420'</code>. Please tell me how can i use group by command to get data from another table.

Answer (score 0):

I would start a new Query based on your **Transaction_Table**.  Then I would add a Merge step, joining to your 1st Query on **Account_No**.  Then I would Expand the **Start_Date** and **End_Date** from the generated **NewColumn**.

Next I would Add a Custom Column, and write a formula like this:

`= [Transaction_Date] >= [Start_Date] and [Transaction_Date] <= [End_Date]`

The resulting column will show TRUE or FALSE.  Filter for TRUE.

Finally I would add a **Group By** step to Sum and Count as required.

I hope I've understood your requirement correctly - it wasn't really clear from your question.